# Delay in jQuery animation

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate, scrolltop

I'm trying to animate the opacity of a div using jQuery. It works fine when I don't use this if/else statement, but when I do, there is a delay before the animation takes place. I tried setting delay to '0' but that didn't help. Here is the code:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){ 

    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 60){ 
        $('#navStick').fadeTo("slow", 1);
    } else {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() <= 60){
            $('#navStick').fadeTo("slow", 0);
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: Why the second `if` statement? That's a given!

Comment: For some reason when I added the second     if statement it sped it up.

Comment: Sorry, but that is *impossible* (I don't use that word often in regards to programming).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Joseph Silber said, the second `if` statement is redundant. Control will only reach that point if it's less than or equal to 60.

Try using `.stop(true)` before your animations

```
$(window).scroll(function(){ 

    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 60){ 
        $('#navStick').stop(true).fadeTo("slow", 1);
    } else {
        $('#navStick').stop(true).fadeTo("slow", 0);
    }

});
```

Comment: No need to `clearQueue` separately. Just use `stop(true)`. See [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/stop/).